# Persisting A Transaction Receipt: "transactionReceipt" is deprecated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have been working for a while to give my app a "Pro Version" with more features. I have been following [Apple's StoreKit Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/StoreKitGuide.pdf) to make this happen but there is a tiny concern I have regarding persisting the transaction receipt of a completed IAP.

If you scroll down to page 27 of the document I linked to above you will find a code snippet that contains the following line:

```
NSData *newReceipt = transaction.transactionReceipt;
```

The concern I have is that the `transactionReceipt` property is deprecated as of iOS 7.

I hate using deprecated code. And in this case it is a big problem because if Apple's documentation isn't updated to reflect changes for iOS 7, where am I supposed to get instructions to make this work 'properly'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pull down your receipts like this (untested):

```
NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```